# In nifi custom processor how to use expression language on content

Tags: apache-nifi, hdf

In nifi expression language only supports attributes. But is I want to use it on content in custom processor. Is it possble to use?.

Comment: No, this is not a supported use. The functions available in the Expression Language are all available with standard processors, and can be replicated using Java code in a custom processor as well.

Comment: Actually in a custom processor it's possible...

Comment: Is there any example for this